# bavix/laravel-wallet new updated function to get transfers data from database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a tiktok like app which retrieve data from mysql database using api from laravel, first i was using bavix/laravel-wallet package version 5.3.2. to create a virtual wallet for gift system in the app. And i have a function which used to send gift to another user (coins) and that user receive gifts in his wallet, i display a list of the Items which contain a number and value of the gifts he received from other users so he can redeem them later.
below is the class which was used to retrieve list of the gift of the user to and display on his wallet ready to be redeemed..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Item as ItemModel;
use Bavix\Wallet\Models\Transfer;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
class Gift extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        static $currency;
        if (empty($currency)) {
            $code = setting('payment_currency', config('fixtures.payment_currency'));
            $symbol = $code;
            $currency = $symbol !== $code ? $symbol : $code;
        }

        $data = [];
        /** @var \App\Models\User $this */
        /** @var ItemModel $item */

        foreach (ItemModel::get() as $item) {
            $transfers = $this->transfers()
                ->where('to_type', $item->getMorphClass())
                ->where('to_id', $item->getKey())   
                ->where('status', Transfer::STATUS_PAID)
                ->count();

            $data[] = [
                'item' => Item::make($item),
                'balance' => $transfers,
                'value' => sprintf('%s%.2f', $currency, ($item->value * $transfers) / 100),
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

The above class was getting a list of all the gifts which was received by the current user in the transfers table and 'to_type' column was returning the Item modal(App/Models/Item) and i was get the result correctly.

But the question here is when i update my laravel to verion 9 and bavix/laravel-wallet to version 9.0 the transfers variable return 0 data from the database because 'to_type' column in database change and does not return Item modal anymore otherwise it returning the Wallet Model and I have no idea how to change my codes to get the same result as from the previous versions.
I read the package documentation but i did not get any luck.

Below is the Item Model class ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Bavix\Wallet\Interfaces\Customer;
use Bavix\Wallet\Interfaces\ProductInterface;
use Bavix\Wallet\Traits\HasWallet;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\LogOptions;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class Item extends Model implements ProductInterface
{
    use HasWallet, LogsActivity;

    // protected static $logFillable = true;
    // protected static $logOnlyDirty = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'image', 'price', 'value', 'minimum',
    ];

    /**
     * @param Customer $customer
     * @param int $quantity
     * @param bool $force
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
    {
        return LogOptions::defaults()
        ->logFillable()
        ->logOnlyDirty();
    }

    public function canBuy(Customer $customer, int $quantity = 1, bool $force = null): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getAmountProduct(Customer $customer): int|string
    {

        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getDescriptionForEvent(string $event): string
    {
        return sprintf('Item "%s" was %s.', $this->name, $event);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMetaProduct(): ?array
    {
        return ['title' => $this->name];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUniqueId(): string
    {
        return (string)$this->getKey();
    }
}
```

Below is the item Db...

[image: Item Table]

Below is the Transfer table

[image: Transfers table]

Below is the Wallet Table

[image: Wallets Table]

Anyone who can help or get any direction on where to read so i can understand how to accomplish that..

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow the greatest, please get a [tour] and learn [ask] providing [mcve]. upgrading a library from one version to another involves ardurous task for most in which [library maintainer provides a how-to guide which you should follow](https://bavix.github.io/laravel-wallet/#/upgrade-guide). should you miss some, you might broke important things. `->where('to_type', $item->getMorphClass())` doesn't work meant internally (on the app side), the name may have changed but not reflected in the database.

Comment: spefically running `artisan bx:transfer:fix` in the version 8.1 to 9.x upgrade guide. that particular code updates the `to_type` column entries, see [code here](https://github.com/bavix/laravel-wallet/blob/master/src/Commands/TransferFixCommand.php#L19). given you provided zero information on how you did the upgrade stuff, i could only suggest minor things you can try.

Comment: hello @BagusTesa thanks for your comments unfortunately when i run the command  it did not solve or change anything otherwise it  throw an error `The command artisan was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default`  if you have any other suggestion i could try i will be happy to hear it. thanks

Comment: first, please clarify on your upgrade path. just executing a command might not solve stuff, doubly and triple check that upgrade guide link above. assessing the proper upgrade path is part of developer's job. those being said, in regard to the "command artisan was not found" thing, you need to do `php artisan bx:transfer:fix` just like how you run laravel migration.

Comment: and i also read transferFixCommand file i think it has a solution to the problem but i did not know how to apply to my code. Am beginner so if you can help me on that it will be helpful.thanks